# node.js shell environment variable conflict with cakephp

Tags: shell, cakephp, node.js

I have set cakes environment path in my .profile file, but it seems the

```
> cake
```

has taken by node.js coffeescript, and outputs the following error

```
node.js:201
    throw e; // process.nextTick error, or 'error' event on first tick
          ^
Error: Cakefile not found in /Users/Devric
    at /opt/local/lib/node_modules/coffee-script/lib/coffee-script/cake.js:96:11
    at /opt/local/lib/node_modules/coffee-script/lib/coffee-script/cake.js:95:32
    at /opt/local/lib/node_modules/coffee-script/lib/coffee-script/cake.js:95:32
    at Object.run (/opt/local/lib/node_modules/coffee-script/lib/coffee-script/cake.js:46:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/opt/local/lib/node_modules/coffee-script/bin/cake:7:38)
    at Module._compile (module.js:432:26)
    at Object..js (module.js:450:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:351:31)
    at Function._load (module.js:310:12)
    at Array.0 (module.js:470:10)
```

Comment: What were you expecting it to do, and why can't you just call it directly?

Comment: um.. to use cake command for cakephp, not the node cakefile. If i call cake shell through a path, than the path is locked to where the shell is stored, which isn't ideal to bake apps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed the issue, by renaming the cake shell for cakephp to cakes, so that it won't conflict with the coffeescript cake file.